# svnkit Error:org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: connection refused by the server

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I use svnkit to checkout svn, I get this error on server(Centos7.6):

```
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/***/***'
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: connection refused by the server
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/***/***'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:112)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.getLocations(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:178)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.createRepositoryFor(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:43)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.checkout(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:831)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:26)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:11)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgOperationRunner.run(SvnNgOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1239)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient.java:777)
    ...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: 拒绝连接 (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.connect(SVNSocketFactory.java:164)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory._createSSLSocket(SVNSocketFactory.java:124)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createSSLSocket(SVNSocketFactory.java:94)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.connect(HTTPConnection.java:237)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:415)
    ... 36 more
```

But when I test this application on my own computer which system is windows 10,it work very well.I can checkout, I can commit and so on without error. I can find what's wrong, what I know is svn service work fine.I think it maybe network problem, but I not sure because ping the svn server IP is return OK.
Help me!
My code below:
pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
    <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Java:

```
public long checkout(SVNClientManager clientManager, SVNURL url,
                                SVNRevision revision, File destPath, SVNDepth depth) {

        SVNUpdateClient updateClient = clientManager.getUpdateClient();
        /*
         * sets externals not to be ignored during the checkout
         */
        updateClient.setIgnoreExternals(false);
        /*
         * returns the number of the revision at which the working copy is
         */
        try {
            return updateClient.doCheckout(url, destPath, revision, revision, depth, false);
//            return updateClient.doCheckout(url, destPath, revision, revision, depth, true);
        } catch (SVNException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should check that traffic is going in/out with a sniffer (wireshark or tshark) , either on your box or on the svn server.

Comment: I give up...but I think the question maybe on the network